# Sharepoint calendar edit series updates

Tags: calendar

I work from a sharepoint 2007 calendar with tasks that have 'new' and 'completed' status.  When I edit the series all of the past 'completed' events switch back to an 'open' status.  Is there a programming change that will allow me to edit series without changing the status of prior events?